# SonarQube Scanner - Long pause between plugin downloads

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarscanner

Maven Sonar scanner is taking a long time to download the plugins ( [INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=495872ms) approx. 9 mins every time a build is triggered. Also, the cache is not working as the builds are triggered on the cloud (Azure DevOps)) with an agentless/serverless architecture. What could be solutions to reduce this time that is built faster?

```
[INFO] User cache: /home/vsts/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 7.9.1
[INFO] Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=1097ms
[INFO] Server id: #####-$$xxxxx$$$
[INFO] User cache: /home/vsts/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load/download plugins
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=211ms
[INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=495872ms
[INFO] Loaded core extensions: developer-scanner
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a self-hosted agent to run the pipeline. So that the plugins can be cached on the local agent machine. Refer to the detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) to create self-hosted agent.

You can also manually download the plugin jars with its dependencies, and include them in the code repo. Then you can install them manually in your pipeline using a script task to run below commands:  See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`

For example:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/plugins/sonar-maven-plugin-3.6.0.1398.jar -DgroupId=org.sonarsource.scanner.maven -DartifactId=sonar-maven-plugin -Dversion=3.6.0.1398 -Dpackaging=jar`

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/plugins/sonar-scanner-api-2.12.0.1661.jar -DgroupId=org.sonarsource.scanner.api -DartifactId=sonar-scanner-api -Dversion=2.12.0.1661 -Dpackaging=jar
```

You can also try using `maven-install-plugin` in pom file to install the local jars. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) for more information.